# Proofs of inverse trigonometric integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have seen plenty of proofs of the derivative forms of arcsin, arctan, arcsec...  However, I would like a proof of how to go from $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +4}}dx $$

WITHOUT memorizing that info in the table.

I think the best way to do it is via drawing the triangle, but I don't know how to do it, and I can't find a proof anywhere.

Comment: The standard first calculus approach is to let $x=2\tan\theta$. We end up integrating $\sec \theta$, somewhat unpleasant. Better is $x=2\sinh t$.

Comment: The integrand should be $\frac{1}{x^2+4}$ to get the result.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Uh you are right I edited it

Answer (score 1):

You can first use the substitution $x=2\tan \theta$, and simplify, the integral result becomes $$ \sec\theta +c=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}+c$$ 
(*HINT:* To get its value just draw a a right angle triangle with sides $x$ and $2$) 
If the integral is without square root the result will be$$\frac{1}{2} \theta+c=\frac{1}{2} \arctan \frac{x}{2}+c$$
If you face any problem please just let know

Comment: Good points. +1

Comment: Thank you for the response. That helped quite a bit.